# Can't create table. Stupid issue, simple query

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
CREATE TABLE `2m_aperturas_credito` (
  `idaperturacredito` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreapertura` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `activo` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idaperturacredito`),
  KEY `idaperturacredito` (`idaperturacredito`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This gave me an error:

[Err] 1005 - Can't create table 'mydb.2m_aperturas_credito' (errno: -1)

What can be wrong here??

Comment: Emm, maybe wrong database? Are you sure you are putting this into "mydb" database? Also fix the AUTO_INCREMENT to 0 or 1, not sure. I think you want to start the database counting from 1 right?

Comment: i think you can't start a table name with a number, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200351/what-characters-are-valid-in-an-sql-server-database-name

Comment: @Groben The answer in that link seems to contradict what you say. That link also refers to sql server.

Comment: could it be a constraint issue?  and are you sure the table doesn't already exist...?  maybe?

Comment: there is no contradiction: "When the compatibility level is 100 (which, according to SQL Server Management Studio, means "SQL Server 2008"), the name must start with a Unicode letter, _, @, or #; followed by one or more letters, numbers, @, $, #, or _." It must not start with a number. You have better explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917064/table-or-column-name-cannot-start-with-numeric

Comment: [If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html)(seems unlikely?  but that's a link to official docs)

Comment: Probably a corrupted tablespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218872/delete-a-crashed-innodb-table

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Reference manual: Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

> It is recommended that you do not use names that begin with `Me` or `MeN`, where `M` and `N` are integers. For example, avoid using `1e` as an identifier, because an expression such as `1e+3` is ambiguous. Depending on context, it might be interpreted as the expression `1e + 3` or as the number `1e+3`.

That said, as a general rule, avoid using numbers at the start of an object name (databases, tables, columns, procedures, functions, variables, etcetera). Try creating the table without the number.