# Remove corrupt table mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a corrupt table in my mysql db, that I want to remove.
It is a table that I do not use anymore, so it can be removed without any problems.

I already tried to repair the table, but then I get the following:

```
catalog_product_flat_1  repair  Error   Incorrect information in file: './catalog_product_flat_1.frm'
catalog_product_flat_1  repair  error   Corrupt
```

I can also not drop the table:

```
DROP TABLE catalog_product_flat_1
Unknown table 'catalog_product_flat_1'
```

How can I remove this table?

Comment: your syntax is wrong, it's DROP TABLE catalog_product_flat_1

Comment: @rockstar Sorry, I did not wrote the right action. See my edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218872/delete-a-crashed-innodb-table